# Increment based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns: group and level range. Each "group" has a list of fruits, and each "level range" has the range of levels like "L1-L4".

*The desired result is the "Fruit" and "Level" columns in the image below.*

So if the range was "L2-L3", the level column would say "2" for 1 row, then "3" for the next row. I'd also like to add each item in the "Group" list to the "Fruit" column.

Any help at all would be appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Here is the work I've done:

I created 2 helper columns: "level_repeat" and "grouping_repeat" to help me duplicate the necessary rows.

```
df['level_repeat'] = df['Level'].replace(['L1-L6', 'L1-L2', 'L1-L3', 'L4-L6', 'L3-L6', 'L2-L6'], [6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])

df['grouping_repeat'] = df['Group'].str.len()

df_new = pd.DataFrame([df.ix[idx] for idx in df.index
                        for _ in range(df.ix[idx]['level_repeat'])]).reset_index(drop=True)

df_new = pd.DataFrame([df_new.ix[idx] for idx in df_new.index
                        for _ in range(df_new.ix[idx]['grouping_repeat'])]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is that I would have 10 rows for the example above, where the group has 2 items and the level range spans 5 levels (2*5=10). However, I still need help with inserting the data into the "Fruit" and "Level" columns.

Comment: Can you post some code of the work that you have already done? So that it is clear which step is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, I would first create a column 'level_list' from 'Level Range' with the `range` of numbers, so for 'L2-L5', the list would be [2,3,4,5].

```
df['level_list'] = (df['Level Range'].str.split('-',expand=True)
                     .stack().str[-1].unstack()
                     .apply(lambda x: range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1),1))
```

now, using product from itertools and the two columns with list (Group and level_list), you can create the new dataframe:

```
from itertools import product
df_new = pd.DataFrame([ [ind, group, level_range, g, l] 
                        for ind, group, level_range, level_list 
                             in df[['Group','Level Range', 'level_list']].itertuples() 
                                   for l, g in product(level_list, group) ], 
                      columns = ['original_ind','Group', 'Level Range', 'Fruit','Level'])
```

with input like

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':[['Apple','Banana']], 'Level Range': ['L2-L5']})`,

the result for `df_new` is:

```
   original_ind            Group Level Range   Fruit  Level
0             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5   Apple      2
1             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5  Banana      2
2             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5   Apple      3
3             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5  Banana      3
4             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5   Apple      4
5             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5  Banana      4
6             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5   Apple      5
7             0  [Apple, Banana]       L2-L5  Banana      5
```

Note if you don't care about the original index, you can drop the column or not create it

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure how to do this without iterating over the dataframe. There might be a better solution but it doesn't come to me. Anyways :

```
res = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    group = row['Group']
    lv_range_str = row['Level Range']

    #change this line if the format of 'Level Range' changes
    lv_range = range(lv_range_str[1], lv_range_str[4] + 1)

    res += [
        {
            'Group': group,
            'Level Range': lv_range_str,
            'Fruit': fruit,
            'Level': level
        }
        for level in lv_range
        for fruit in group
    ]

res = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

It will only work if all the strings in `Level Range` are in the format `L{i}-L{j}`, else you will need to change the definition of `lv_range`
It might take some time if your dataset is big though

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract the range from the string `L1-L5` as `[1,2,3,4,5]` and create a dataframe with the product of this list and the fruit list `[Apple, Banana]`.

You could use either `itertools.product` or `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` for this operation.

Here, I'm using the latter & a helper function to build the range.

```
def get_level_range(x):
    a, b = x.replace('L', '').split('-')
    return range(int(a), int(b)+1)

dframes = []
for _, x in df.iterrows():
    dframes.append(
        pd.DataFrame(
            index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                [get_level_range(x['Level Range']), x.Group, 
                 [tuple(x.Group)], [x['Level Range']]], 
                names=['Level', 'Fruit', 'Group', 'Level Range']
            )
        ).reset_index()
    )

pd.concat(dframes)

# produces output:

   Level   Fruit            Group Level Range
0      1   Apple  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
1      1  Banana  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
2      2   Apple  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
3      2  Banana  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
4      3   Apple  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
5      3  Banana  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
6      4   Apple  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
7      4  Banana  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
8      5   Apple  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
9      5  Banana  (Apple, Banana)       L1-L5
```

The 1 caveat is that `Group` needs to get converted from `list` to `tuple`, because list is not hashable, and therefore not usable as an index element. But it is possible to convert it back to a `list` later if you want, like this:

```
out.Group = out.Group.apply(list)
```